# static opencv cannot find USB webcam on arm Linux busybox?

Tags: c++, opencv, usb, webcam, busybox

I have a small busybox system for which I compiled the kernel and added support for USB cameras. When when I connect the camera to the device it gives me some output and I get a /dev/video0 device:

```
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using orion-ehci
uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Webcam C170 (046d:082b)
input: Webcam C170 as /devices/platform/orion-ehci.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input1

/ # ls -l /dev/video0
crw-rw----    1 0        0          81,   0 Mar  8 08:08 /dev/video0
/ #
```

I have statically compiled opencv2.4 for arm with all needed libs and get no error compiling the code:

```
Mat frame;
VideoCapture capture(0);
if(!capture.isOpened()){
    printf("Cannot open camera\r\n");
    printf("%s\r\n", cvErrorStr(cvGetErrStatus()));
}
```

which gives me as output:

```
Cannot open camera
No Error
/ #
```

The camera works fine on my laptop and I have tried multiple camera's all with the same result. I have also tried many different ways of opening the camera trough opencv which also gave me the same results.

How can I get my busybox system and opencv to read from the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing V4L. I would run the sample code for V4L and investigate that. Did you check with ldd that you have all the libraries you program is linked against?

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing, but i have opencv compiled statlicy and same goes for the code i have written, opencv was compiled with most of the extra's such as WITH_V4L etc. I have also made sure to compile the kernel with support for UVC camera's and V4L Devices etc. I will try to compile a dynamic exec and copy the needed libs over to the target device when i have some time to put in this project sometime this week and get back to you.

Comment: So i have found the problem and was able to fix it. When configuring OpenCV with cmake i made sure v4l support was enabled but when building the library v4l was actualy not compiled with the actuallibs. Somewhere between all the compile output i was getting aerrors about the v4l1 and v4l2 libs not being found. So i compiled the v4l libs from source, copied them in the cross lib folder and voila!